# Data visualization on map

Tags: javascript, vue.js, statistics, data-visualization

I’m working on a vuejs project, I want to make some data visualisation on a map: display a map and show some percentages for each country. I really do not know from where to start. What tools to use ? Is there some tutorials  and javascript libraries that can help ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to show some percentages on each country, and you don't need those detail information on the maps, maybe you don't need Google Maps.

Try D3.js. There are several examples you can build with. [DataMaps](http://datamaps.github.io/) would be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the google maps api, they have good documentation on all their stuff. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/
It should be noted however that these days you need a account with billing information to use their maps api's.
to be honest your question is so broad that if i were you i would first start to brainstorm and get a good grasp about what i wanted to do and how to do it.